# Running loop on a dictionary and a list to check if dictironary values comes in range of list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I wanted to know if it is possible to run loop on Dictionary to check if it's value is in range of a given list indexes, like I have a dictionary:

```
fitness_prob with this values: {<Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A4BCF8>: 2.7073187389600226e-07, <Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A4BCC0>: 2.9819203163310753e-07, <Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A78160>: 3.2173549856232664e-07, <Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A78198>: 2.643299134420016e-07, <Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A781D0>: 2.94518321996265e-07}
```

And a list

```
points[] : [1.0027919514838946e-05, 0.010010027919514839, 0.02001002791951484, 0.030010027919514837, 0.04001002791951484, 0.050010027919514845, 0.06001002791951484, 0.07001002791951484, 0.08001002791951484]
```

list would be like a scale with its value as a marker and loop should Identify dictionary values which comes in those marker range. Like :

**Expected output:**

> **First**, check the range of points[0] and points[1]
>
> **Second**, append all values from fitness_prob{} coming in these values to a new dictionary with `key`: `value` new_pool{}

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is usually "yes" -- you're using a general-purpose language on a general-purpose computer, so you have full Turing potential.  The implied question behind this, "how do I do it?" is an open-ended, individualized tutorial, which is *seriously* off-topic for Stack Overflow -- please re-take the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I will add code that I tried..

Comment: I'm guessing this will be the code from your last question?

Comment: yes, it was actually making a lot of iteration on that. Even for small input of values. Logic I tried over there wasn't even near to efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `points`, and then use a dictionary comprehension to get the elements of the `fitness_prob` elements whose values are in each range.

```
results = []
for i in range(len(points)-1):
    start = points[i]
    end = points[i+1]
    results.append({key: value for key, value in fitness_prob.items() if start <= value < end})
```

Comment: This worked. One more thing is it possible to do this other way round? Like to keep dictionary values as marker and see how many points comes in that range?

Comment: Don't understand. The dictionary values are just single numbers, not ranges.

Comment: I mean taking value of dictionary like for `fitness_prob={<Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A4BCF8>: **2.7073187389600226e-07**, <Individual.Individual object at 0x000001A7F5A4BCC0>: **2.9819203163310753e-07**}` and then checking on list if there is any value in between  this .

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, so how do you know how to pair up the dictionary entries? You could make a list of the dictionary values, sort them, and then use the same algorithm, just swapping the roles.